# Using a Yew Callback as a wasm_bindgen Closure

Tags: rust, callback, closures, wasm-bindgen, yew

> This question is written for Yew v0.19

Asynchronous foreign JavaScript functions can be used in Rust through [Closures](https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-bindgen/api/wasm_bindgen/closure/struct.Closure.html#), as the function to pass-in:

```rust
#[wasm_bindgen]
extern "C" {
    fn setInterval(closure: &Closure<dyn FnMut()>, time: u32) -> i32;
}

// ...

let cb = Closure::new(|| {
    log("interval elapsed!");
});

let interval_id = setInterval(&cb, 1_000);
```

This is nice for a pedantic examples, but `Closure`s have a critical requirement - the function applied needs to have a `'static` lifetime. Likewise, with Yew applications, a perfect mechanism for spontaneous response is the `Message` enum, and having it `update()` the `Model`. However, the `link()` mechanism in `Context` (which issues messages) does **not** have a static lifetime.

In an ideal world, the value submitted to the closure could just be applied as a Yew component message:

```rust
struct Model {
    thing: Option<JsValue>,
}

enum Msg {
    GotThing(JsValue),
}

#[wasm_bindgen]
extern "C" {
    fn createThing(closure: &Closure<dyn FnMut(JsValue) -> ());
}

impl Component for Model {
    type Message = Msg;
    type Properties = ();

    fn create(_ctx: &Context<Self>) -> Self {
        Model {
            thing: None, // initial value
        }
    }

    fn update(&mut self, _ctx: &Context<Self>, msg: Self::Message) -> bool {
        match msg {
            Msg::GotThing(x) => { // handle the message
                self.thing = Some(x);
                true
            },
        }
    }

    fn rendered(&mut self, ctx: &Context<Self>, first_render: bool) {
        if first_render {
            let cb: Box<dyn FnMut(JsValue) -> ()> = Box::new(|x| {
                // try and issue the message
                ctx.link().send_message(Msg::GotThing(x));
                // ^ doesn't have a `'static` lifetime! Won't compile
            });
            createThing(Closure::wrap(&cb));
        }
    }

    // fn view() ... omitted, not relevant
}
```

I'm wondering if there's a way to *convert* a `Callback` into a `Closure`, or if there's a better, more canonical way to do this, to please correct me.

Another idea I had would use some kind of queue defined statically (which wouldn't be safe as it's a mutable static variable), but then it could be used as an intermediary data type between the `Closure` passed to `createThing`, and messages could be dispatched within the component.

Maybe there's an external way to interact with a Yew component that I'm overlooking? I'm not sure how to resolve this issue. What would be the most correct way to achieve this goal?

Comment: Excellent question - I currently struggle with the same problem. Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: This could help me [solve a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75203156) - calling a Yew callback from JS to change the Yew route.

Comment: Looks like [this gist](https://gist.github.com/craftyc0der/1e71964cc3e85d533f0f70985c22a74a#setup-wasm-bindgen-for-the-javascript-code) from [craftyc0der](https://gist.github.com/craftyc0der) may provide one way of doing this.

Comment: I've found that a (somewhat unnatural) way of getting around this is to use async_channels, but I don't have a complete working example.